# airplane mode and accelerometer

Tags: android, ios, iphone, accelerometer

Does anyone know how to detect if an iphone or android-enabled phone is in a flying plane or not. Would accelerometer readings be of enough reliability to detect such status. My use case is for enabling flight-mode automatically. Thank you.

Comment: You can't enable flight mode programatically on iOS and an accelerometer measure acceleration, not velocity so it would be difficult to correlate acceleration with being in a plane

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks. is there a way to detect if a phone is in a plane then?

Comment: Related: [How can I find the velocity using accelerometers only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085583/how-can-i-find-the-velocity-using-accelerometers-only), [Measuring velocity via iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994018/measuring-velocity-via-iphone-sdk) and [How to determine the velocity of an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724017/how-to-determine-the-velocity-of-an-android-device)

Comment: And you also have [Detect airplane mode on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804398/iphone-detect-airplane-mode) and [How can one detect airplane mode on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319212/how-can-one-detect-airplane-mode-on-android)

Comment: @jww, thank you. The airplane mode does not mean you are flying in an airplane ;)